# how to extract URI from bunch of URLs?

Tags: python

I have bunch of urls.
And i have to extract all the uri from urls.

e.g:

```
https://home/a/b/c,
https://home/d/e/f,
https://home/g/h/i,
https://home/j/k/l
```

I have to extract everything after `https://home/` in python.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple, just use `str.split()`:

```
>>> str = "https://home/a/b/c"
>>> str.split("https://home/")[1]
a/b/c
```

So for a list of urls:

```
urls = ["https://home/a/b/c", "https://home/d/e/f",
        "https://home/g/h/i", "https://home/j/k/l"]

new_urls = [url.split("https://home/")[1] for url in urls]
print(new_urls)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> ['a/b/c', 'd/e/f', 'g/h/i', 'j/k/l']
> ```